# At what decibel does Android Pie shows high volume warning?

Tags: volume

At what decibel does Android Pie shows high volume warning?

Answer (score 0):

According to an article [here](https://appuals.com/how-to-disable-volume-warning-on-android/) by Kevin Arrows:

> The reason Android phones [give high volume warning] is due to regulations set by the European Committee for Electrotechnical Standardization, which dictate that media playback devices must have a maximum output value of 85 dB – past 85 dB and the user must accept a warning.

So, the decibel limit might be 85 in Android Pie.

Comment: By "volume limit", did you mean "the maximum decibel an Android device can play", or "the warning threshold"? Note that the article is talking about "the warning threshold" that the user has to accept before turning the volume louder than that.

Comment: I was talking about the warning threshold. Not the maximum decibel that's possible on an android device.